# Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, publish, shinyapps

```
# ===============================================
# Fill in the following fields
# ===============================================
# Title: Text Analysis of Harry Potter Books
# Description: Shiny app to visualize the results from a text analysis performed on the seven Harry Potter books
# Author: Seoyoung Park
# Date: 2023-04-27


# ===============================================
# Packages
# ===============================================
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(ggplot2)
library(rsconnect)

# ===============================================
# Import data
# ===============================================
hp_books = read_csv("harry_potter_books.csv", col_types = "ccc")

load("afinn.rda")
# ===============================================
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='sypark12',
                          token='A2A927368E0CBE69BD5EC986A476D4BF',
                          secret='3SswpuHTYizhLkldRJ5AaNSlArZsL2YuZPESQbOz')
# ===============================================

# ===============================================
# Define "ui" for application
# ===============================================
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Text Analysis of Harry Potter Books"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           p(em("Setting books")),
           selectInput(inputId = "select1", 
                       label = "Select a Specified Book",
                       choices = c("Book 1: Philosopher's Stone" = "sel1",
                                   "Book 2: Chamber of Secrets" = "sel2",
                                   "Book 3: Prisoner of Azkaban" = "sel3",
                                   "Book 4: Goblet of Fire" = "sel4",
                                   "Book 5: Order of the Phoenix" = "sel5",
                                   "Book 6: Half Blood Prince" = "sel6",
                                   "Book 7: Deathly Hallows" = "sel7"),
                       selected = "sel1")
    ),
    
    
    column(3,
           p(em("Analysis1: Write up to 3 words to see their usage across chapters of a book")),
           textInput(inputId = "text1",
                     label = "Text Input",
                     value = "harry"
           ),
           textInput(inputId = "text2",
                     label = "Text Input 2",
                     value = "ron"
           ),
           textInput(inputId = "text3",
                     label = "Text Input 3",
                     value = "hermione"
           )
    ),

    
    column(3,
           p(em("Analysis2: Make a selection of criterias for the sentiment analysis and aesthetics for the word frequencies")),
           sliderInput(inputId = "size1",
                       label = "Number of words to display",
                       min = 1,
                       max = 30,
                       value = 25),
           sliderInput(inputId = "size2",
                       label = "Size of the labels",
                       min = 1,
                       max = 20,
                       value = 12)
    ),
    
    column(3,
           p(em("Common parameters")),
           checkboxInput(inputId = "checkbox",
                         label = "Removing common words (stopwords)",
                         value = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  hr(),
  
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Analysis1",
                       h3("Word Trend Analaysis"),
                       plotOutput("plot1"),
                       hr(),
                       dataTableOutput("table1")),
              tabPanel("Analysis2", 
                       h3("Frequencies / Sentiment Analysis"),
                       plotOutput("plot2"),
                       hr(),
                       dataTableOutput('table2'))
  )
)


# ===============================================
# Define Server "server" logic
# ===============================================

server = function(input, output) {
  
  # Load the selected book
  selected_book <- reactive({
    switch(input$select1,
           "sel1" = "Book 1: Philosopher's Stone",
           "sel2" = "Book 2: Chamber of Secrets",
           "sel3" = "Book 3: Prisoner of Azkaban",
           "sel4" = "Book 4: Goblet of Fire",
           "sel5" = "Book 5: Order of the Phoenix",
           "sel6" = "Book 6: Half Blood Prince",
           "sel7" = "Book 7: Deathly Hallows")
  })
  

  # Create a data frame with the word frequencies for the selected words
  words_df <- reactive({
    hp_books %>%
      filter(book == selected_book()) %>%
      mutate(chapter = str_remove(chapter, "chap-")) %>%
      unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text) %>%
      transform(Chapter = as.numeric(chapter)) %>%
      filter(word %in% c(input$text1, input$text2, input$text3)) %>%
      group_by(Chapter) %>%
      count(word)
  })
  
  # Remove common words if the check box is checked
  filtered_words_df <- reactive({
    if (input$checkbox == TRUE) {
      words_df() %>%
        anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")
    } else {
      words_df()
    }
  })
  

  
  # Load the slider input value of number of words for show
  slider_value <- reactive({
    input$size1
  })
  
  # Load the slider input value for size of labels
  label_size <- reactive({
    input$size2
  })
  
  # Tokenizing the data frame by words
  tidy_df <- reactive({
    hp_books %>%
      filter(book == selected_book()) %>%
      mutate(chapter = str_remove(chapter, "chap-")) %>%
      unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text) %>%
      transform(Chapter = as.numeric(chapter)) %>%
      group_by(word) %>%
      count(word) %>%
      arrange(desc(n)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      inner_join(bing, by = "word") 
  })
  
  # Remove common words if the check box is checked
  filtered_tidy_df <- reactive({
    if (input$checkbox == TRUE) {
      tidy_df() %>%
        anti_join(stop_words, by = "word")
    } else {
      tidy_df()
    }
  })
# ===============================================
# Outputs for the first TAB
# ===============================================

  # Plot the word frequencies
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
      ggplot(data = filtered_words_df(),
             aes(x = Chapter, y = n, color = word)) +
      geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
      labs(x = "Chapter", y = "Frequencies (count)", title = "Word Frequencies by Chapter:") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 40, 1)) +
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray60", size = 0.2),
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(color = "gray60", size = 0.2),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "black"),
            axis.title = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
            legend.title = element_text(size = 13),
            legend.text = element_text(size = 10)
            )
  })
  
  # code for numeric summaries of frequencies
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    filtered_words_df() %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = "word", values_from = "n")
  })

# ===============================================
# Outputs for the second TAB
# ===============================================
  
  # code for plot2
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

      ggplot(data = filtered_tidy_df()%>%
               slice_head(n = slider_value())) +
      geom_col(aes(x = reorder(word, n), y = n, fill = sentiment)) +
      coord_flip() +
      labs(title = "Most common words with an associated sentiment", x = "", y = "") +
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray60", size = 0.2),
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(color = "gray60", size = 0.2),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "black"),
            axis.title = element_text(size = 13),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = label_size()),
            legend.title = element_text(size = 13),
            legend.text = element_text(size = 10)
      )
  })
  
  # code for statistics
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    filtered_tidy_df()
  })
  
}
# ===============================================
# Run the application
# ===============================================

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can download harry_potter_books.csv here: https://github.com/gastonstat/harry-potter-data/blob/main/csv-data-file/harry_potter_books.csv

I would like to publish it in shinyapps.io, however, when I tried, it did not work and the error happened. So I checked my log, and there was an warning message such as Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero. Could you help me know how can I solve this?

Comment: Instead of `input$checkbox == TRUE` try doing `isTRUE(input$checkbox)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it still make same error message after I try isTRUE(input$checkbox).

Comment: Where is your `bing` dataset? Specifically looking at your tidy_df, inner_join part